# RadButton Confirmation Dialog Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, telerik

I was trying to create a confirmation dialog but failed. My code is below:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonHelp" runat="server" 
  Text="Help" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="rbButton" 
  OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to open help?')) return false;" 
  OnClick="RadButtonHelp_Click">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Telerik's `RadButton` control includes a built-in feature for displaying confirmation message. On top of that, you can customize the popup window experience by utilising `RadConfirm` or `RadWindow` control, and it's not hard to achieve. Please be sure to check the attached link for more details.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="btnStandardConfirm" runat="server" Text="Standard window.confirm" OnClientClicking="StandardConfirm" OnClick="Button_Click">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RadButton btn = sender as RadButton;
     switch (btn.ID)
     {
         case "btnStandardConfirm":
         Label1.Text = "The <strong>StandardButton</strong> submitted the page at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
         break;
     }
 }
```

JS

```
function StandardConfirm(sender, args) {
    args.set_cancel(!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the page?"));
}
```

Demo Link:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/confirm/defaultcs.aspx